# Get rid of "got flair?" once it's proven that someone has it

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

This is a very minor annoyance, but the fix should be relatively minor also; once a member's flair has been downloaded, stop asking em if ey've "got flair?" Since there's obviously some type of server-side wizardry already going on, unless `.png` files have grown the intelligence to parse query strings (e.g. "?style=dark"), this shouldn't be too hard to implement.

The "flair" settings can be put under the profile editor.

PS those aren't typos, they're [gender neutral pronouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spivak_pronoun)

Comment: "them" and "they've" would do as a gender neutral pronouns.

Comment: If the pronouns have to be explained then they're probably not communicating like language should.

Comment: To English SE! (To 15 chars!)

Comment: Actually, it's only the `new` thing which annoys me. The link itself isn't bothering me.

Comment: This would be equivalent to hiding the "Ask Question" button once somebody has a question in the system

Comment: flair could be editable under the profile like all other settings, once it's no longer "new" to the person who has used it once. gender-neutral pronouns need to be explained because many people don't know there are such things and as a result use plural instead of singular, or he/she/it, or other poor practices, and worse, try to hammer others into doing the same.

Comment: I was pretty sure singular they was [acceptible English as a gender neutral pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/gender-neutral-pronoun).

Comment: it's hard for me to tell if I came across as a jerk the way I asked the question, or if some of you guys just have too much time on your hands. the only person who responded to the issue itself, BalusC, was partially in agreement. so how about it? I've "got flair", stop bothering me about it already.

Comment: @jco You mean besides Lance's answer saying this would be bad, which has 5 upvotes?

Comment: @Michael yes, obviously. as indicated numerous times already, this should be able to be done from the profile editor, no need to have it a special case. Those 5 upvotes are quite possibly from the same 5 people who downvoted the question.

Comment: a greasemonkey script to hide "got flair?" is at http://jc.unternet.net/src/stfuflairboyz.user.js if anyone else wants to use it. comments and improvements are welcome.

Comment: amazingly, privoxy also removes it automatically. plus making one's browsing safer in public places. [update] nope, it's just that google chrome doesn't render it for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally you got rid of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

If someone wants to reload his flair, with or without different parameters, then he'd need a link to do that with.

Comment: Or change the theme.  Or get the combined flair.

Comment: yes, obviously. under the profile editor. not in your face 24/7.

Comment: @jco If it is in your face 24/7 your spending way to much time on your profile page and to little time on the rest of the site.

Comment: touche'. but I haven't figured out a better way to revisit the stuff I answered to see if there's any new input.

Comment: @jcomeau, that's what the favorites list is for. You can set the system to automatically notify you of any changes to your favorites; I can't remember if that's the default or not.

Answer (score 5):

The little highlighted yellow "new" that is next to it since a year and a half should probably be removed.

The flair is by no means new anymore and it's rather inconsistent since no other thing that was introduced has ever been marked up like that.

Comment: I think the "new" was introduced when things were [changed September 22nd](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/)? (That would also explain the consistency: just an indicator for existing users, like the "New, now even crunchier" on breakfast serials.)

Comment: I'm not 100% happy with this answer but it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could stay, but without the yellow "new" sticker.
I'm so in need of these `50`...